# Getting data from Datastore for injection

Tags: ktor, ktor-client

I am trying to retrieve the base url from my proto datastore to be used to initialize my ktor client instance I know how to get the data from the datastore but I don't know how to block execution until that value is received so the client can be initialized with the base url

So my ktor client service asks for a NetworkURLS class which has a method to return the base url

Here is my property to retrieve terminalDetails from my proto datastore

```kotlin
val getTerminalDetails: Flow<TerminalDetails> = cxt.terminalDetails.data
        .catch { e ->
            if (e is IOException) {
                Log.d("Error", e.message.toString())
                emit(TerminalDetails.getDefaultInstance())
            } else {
                throw e
            }
        }
```

Normally when I want to get the values I would do something like this

```
 private fun getTerminalDetailsFromStore() {
        try {
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                localRepository.getTerminalDetails.collect {
                    _terminalDetails.value = it
                }
            }
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            Log.d("AdminSettingsViewModel Error", e.message.toString()) // TODO: Handle Error Properly
        }
    }
```

but in my current case what I am looking to do is return `terminalDetails.backendHost` from a function and that where the issue comes in I know I need to use a coroutine scope to retrieve the value so I don't need to suspend the function but how to a prevent the function returning until the coroutine scope has finished?

I have tried using async and runBlocking but async doesn't work the way I would think it would and runBlocking hangs the entire app

```
fun backendURL(): String = runBlocking {
        var url: String = "localhost"

        val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
            repo.getTerminalDetails.collect {
                it.backendHost
            }
        }

        url
    }
```

Can anyone give me some assistance on getting this to work?

EDIT: Here is my temporary solution, I do not intend on keeping it this way, The issue with `runBlocking{}` turned out to be the `Flow<T>` does not finish so `runBlocking{}` continues to block the app.

```
fun backendURL(): String {
        val details = MutableStateFlow<TerminalDetails>(TerminalDetails.getDefaultInstance())

        val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            repo.getTerminalDetails.collect {
                details.value = it
            }
        }

        runBlocking {
            delay(250L)
        }

        return details.value.backendHost
    }
```

EDIT 2:  I fully fixed my issue. I created a method with the same name as my val (personal decision) which utilizes `runBlocking{}` and `Flow<T>.first()`  to block while the value is retrieve. The reason I did not replace my val with the function is there are places where I need the information as well where I can utilize coroutines properly where I am not initializing components on my app

```
val getTerminalDetails: Flow<TerminalDetails> = cxt.terminalDetails.data
        .catch { e ->
            if (e is IOException) {
                Log.d("Error", e.message.toString())
                emit(TerminalDetails.getDefaultInstance())
            } else {
                throw e
            }
        }

    fun getTerminalDetails(): TerminalDetails = runBlocking {
        cxt.terminalDetails.data.first()
    }
```

Comment: If the value for `backendHost` isn't changed during your application's lifecycle then you can block the app once on a startup to create a client with a default request configuration. Otherwise, since you probably launch HTTP requests under a scope that is different from the scope of UI, you can modify each request to use a value of `backendHost` there without blocking UI.

Comment: thats part of my issue though, I try to block it on startup but the app just hangs, which I figured out was do to my return `Flow<T>`. For the time being I adjusted my method a bit and I run a block on a delay of 250ms which gets be by for now.